# What is the correct syntax to run mongoexport for a remote mongo database?

Tags: mongodb, mongoexport

I wish to export a collection from a remote mongo database.

Locally, i connect to my remote mongo database via the following mongo command:

```
mongo mongodb://<shard-01>,<shard-02>,<shard-03>?replicaSet=shard-0 -ssl --authenticationDatabase admin --username admin --password password
```

By running the command above, i can basically connect to the remote database and run queries there.

Now, i wish to do a mongoexport for this database for a specific collection. But it seems i cannot figure out the correct syntax to do it.

I tried

```
mongoexport mongodb://<shard-01>,<shard-02>,<shard-03>?replicaSet=shard-0 -ssl --authenticationDatabase admin --username admin --password password --collection car --out ./car.json

mongoexport --uri=mongodb://admin:password@<shard-01>,<shard-02>,<shard-03>?replicaSet=shard-0 --collection car --out ./car.json

mongoexport --uri=mongodb://<shard-01>,<shard-02>,<shard-03>?replicaSet=shard-0 --username admin --password password --collection car --out ./car.json
```

But none of those seems to be working. It all complains that

```
error connecting to db server: no reachable servers
```

Comment: by any chance you got it figured? I am wondering the same thing too

Answer (score 4):

mongoexport [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/#cmdoption-mongoexport-uri) states that you can't specify some options when using uri:

> IMPORTANT
>
> The following mongoexport options are incompatible with the --uri option. Instead, specify these options as part of your --uri connection string when applicable:
>
> --host
>
> --port
>
> --db
>
> --username
>
> --password (when specifying the password as part of the URI connection string)
>
> --authenticationDatabase
>
> --authenticationMechanism

So you will need provide a URI based on this [scheme](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/#cmdoption-mongoexport-uri):

> mongodb://[username:password@]host1[:port1][,host2[:port2],...[,hostN[:portN]]][/[database][?options]]

An example would be:

```
mongoexport --uri "mongodb://username:password@test-shard-00-00-1qpma.mongodb.net:27017,test-shard-00-01-1qpma.mongodb.net:27017,test-shard-00-02-1qpma.mongodb.net:27017/collection?replicaSet=test-shard-0&ssl=true&authSource=admin" --collection collectionName --out collectionName-dump.json
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer arguments vs inlining it all, I've used this syntax successfully. The upside is that your password won't be printed in your bash history.

```
mongoexport --uri "mongodb://your-database-server-shard-00-00.asdf8l.mongodb.net:27017,your-database-server-shard-00-01.asdf8l.mongodb.net:27017,your-database-server-shard-00-02.asdf8l.mongodb.net:27017/your-database-name?replicaSet=your-replicaset-name-shard-0" --ssl --authenticationDatabase admin --username your-user --collection your-collection-name --out a-file-name-dump.json
```

You will be prompted for your password.